# What is stopping to update recurring payment or billing details!

Tags: paypal, recurring-contributions, receipts

Some of our donors have reported that they were not able to update the amount or cancel their recurring subscription payment using the standard email receipt that gets sent from CiviCRM. I am using Paypal pro with CiviCRM 5.13.5. When I have tried it myself, I get the following error.

However, if a link is served with checksum for that user then I was able to use UPDATE, CANCEL links!
How can I fix this problem, please? Thanks.

[image]

UPDATE: this is the url I get when I click the link

https://example.com/index.php?q=civicrm/contribute/unsubscribe&reset=1&crid=173&cs=631e63d2b52b3596e18b1f3fe144afc3_1559485259_inf

does it seem all parameters present in the URL?

Answer (score 2):

Test this patch to see if it fixes your problem? https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14407

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am a bit confused while applying this patch!! I am on 5.13.5 and the PHP content of the patch is very different to the file of 5.13.5. For example, ContributionRecur.php code lines of  5.13.5 are very different from the latest patch file. And other 3 files also I found similar things. So, do I replace the entire content of the latest patch file? or apply only the differences, but my fear something might break!! Any thoughts? Thanks again!

Comment: There should be a fix for this in 5.14.0 - dropping today